# Ubuntu take over Android. Are we going to use now GCC or Java NDK/SDK of Android?

Tags: java, android, c, linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu Linux has Android Linux wrapper: http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android

Are we going to now use Android Java NDK/SDK?

- or **GCC** and **natural C** codes with native deployment? like we do in general desktop development?

  - BASH will be back
  - OLD apps will be ported easyly
- or we have to still use there NDK/SDK?

  - was a bit complicated
  - less reinvent of JNA/JNI as i have to rewrite my C to Java again

Comment: I would be more than happy to use C :D

Comment: It's not super clear what you're asking.  Please try to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Ubuntu next to Android, with some elements of file structure (data, mainly, i.e. emails/texts) integrated. You will still program for ubuntu with the same development processes as previously. You will still program for Android with the same development processes as previously.